# Mercurial Remote Subrepos

Tags: mercurial, subrepos

I'm trying to set up my Mercurial repository system to work with multiple subrepos.  I've basically followed [these instructions](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos) to set up the client repo with Mercurial client v1.5 and I'm using [HgWebDir](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) to host my multiple projects.

I have an HgWebDir with the following structure:

```
http://myserver/hg
|-- fooproj
|-- mylib
```

where `mylib` is some collection of common template library to be consumed by `fooproj`.  The structure of `fooproj` looks like this:

```
 fooproj
 |-- doc/
 |   `-- readme
 |-- src/
 |   `-- main.cpp
 |-- .hgignore
 |-- .hgsub
 `-- .hgsubstate
```

And `.hgsub` looks like:

```
src/mylib = http://myserver/hg/mylib
```

This should work, per my interpretation of the documentation:

> The first 'nested' is the path in our
>   working dir, and the second is a URL
>   or path to pull from.

Also, the `mylib` project directory structure looks like this:

```
mylib
|-- .hg
|   |-- 00changelog.i
|   |-- dirstate
|   |-- requires
|   |-- store
|   |   |-- 00changelog.i
|   |   |-- 00manifest.i
|   |   |   |-- data
|   |   |   |   ` magic.h.i
|   |   |-- fncache
|   |   `-- undo
|   |-- undo.branch
|   `-- undo.dirstate
`-- magic.h
```

So, let's say I pull down `fooproj` to my home folder with:

```
~$ hg clone http://myserver/hg/fooproj foo
```

Which pulls down the directory structure properly and adds the folder `~/foo/src/mylib` which is a local Mercurial repository.  This is where the problems begin: the `mylib` folder is empty aside from the items in `.hg`.  The messages from Mercurial are:

```
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 5 changes to 5 files
updating working directory
5 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

With 2 seconds of investigation, one can see the `src/mylib/.hg/hgrc` is:

```
[paths]
default = http://myserver/hg/fooproj/src/mylib
```

which is completely wrong (attempting a `pull` of that repo will give a 404 because, well, that URL doesn't make any sense).

```
foo
|-- .hg
|   |-- 00changelog.i
|   |-- branch
|   |-- branchheads.cache
|   |-- dirstate
|   |-- hgrc
|   |-- requires
|   |-- store
|   |   |-- 00changelog.i
|   |   |-- 00manifest.i
|   |   |-- data
|   |   |   |-- .hgignore.i
|   |   |   |-- .hgsub.i
|   |   |   |-- .hgsubstate.i
|   |   |   |-- doc
|   |   |   |   `-- readme.i
|   |   |   `-- src
|   |   |       `-- main.cpp.i
|   |   |-- fncache
|   |   `-- undo
|   |-- tags.cache
|   |-- undo.branch
|   `-- undo.dirstate
|-- .hgignore
|-- .hgsub
|-- .hgsubstate
|-- doc
|   `-- readme
`-- src
    |-- main.cpp
    `-- mylib
        `-- .hg
            |-- 00changelog.i
            |-- branch
            |-- dirstate
            |-- hgrc
            |-- requires
            `-- store
```

Logically, the default value should be what I specified in `.hgsub` or it would get the files from the repository in some way.  Of course, changing `src/mylib/.hg/hgrc` to:

```
[paths]
default = http://myserver/hg/mylib
```

and running `hg pull && hg update` works perfectly.  Of course, this is basically the same thing as not using subrepos in the first place.

None of the Mercurial commands return error codes (aside from a `pull` from within `src/mylib`), so it clearly believes that it is behaving properly (and just might be), although this does not seem logical at all.

#### What am I doing wrong?

The ultimate problem might be that `.hgsubstate` will always look like:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 src/mylib
```

But I have no idea how to fix that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left-hand-side path in your `.hgsub` file is relative to its location in your tree.  It's already down in `src`, so `src` doesn't need to be in the path.  I think if you make the `.hgsub` file look like:

```
mylib = http://myserver/hg/mylib
```

and leave it where it is you'll get what you want.  Alternately, you could move the location of `.hgsub` up a directory (outside of `src`, in your *root*) and then it would be correct as it is now.

I've just confirmed this interpretation with a setup like this:

```
.
|-- .hg
|   |-- 00changelog.i
|   |-- branch
|   |-- branchheads.cache
|   |-- dirstate
|   |-- last-message.txt
|   |-- requires
|   |-- store
|   |   |-- 00changelog.i
|   |   |-- 00manifest.i
|   |   |-- data
|   |   |   |-- .hgsub.i
|   |   |   `-- .hgsubstate.i
|   |   |-- fncache
|   |   `-- undo
|   |-- undo.branch
|   `-- undo.dirstate
|-- .hgsub
|-- .hgsubstate
`-- src
    `-- mylib
        |-- .hg
        |   |-- 00changelog.i
        |   |-- branch
        |   |-- branchheads.cache
        |   |-- dirstate
        |   |-- hgrc
        |   |-- last-message.txt
        |   |-- requires
        |   |-- store
        |   |   |-- 00changelog.i
        |   |   |-- 00manifest.i
        |   |   |-- data
        |   |   |   |-- .hgignore.i
        |   |   |   |-- _p_k_g-_i_n_f_o.i
        |   |   |   |-- _r_e_a_d_m_e.i
        |   |   |   |-- hgext
        |   |   |   |   `-- chart.py.i
        |   |   |   `-- setup.py.i
        |   |   |-- fncache
        |   |   `-- undo
        |   |-- tags.cache
        |   |-- undo.branch
        |   `-- undo.dirstate
        |-- .hgignore
        |-- PKG-INFO
        |-- README
        |-- hgext
        |   `-- chart.py
        `-- setup.py
```

Where that top level `.hgsub` file contains:

```
$ cat .hgsub
src/mylib = https://Ry4an@bitbucket.org/Ry4an/hg-chart-extension/
```

and a cone done of the parent shows it cloning the child too:

```
$ hg clone parent parent-clone
updating to branch default
pulling subrepo src/mylib
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 8 changesets with 14 changes to 5 files
```

Comment: My `.hgsub` is in the top level directory as well (I guess that wasn't clear)...the problem is that when I clone...it just doesn't pull the subrepo properly.  It works fine if it is in the top-level directory (`mylib = http://myserver/hg/mylib`), but I need to have it check out to `src/mylib`.

Comment: You're right I just misread your tree output.  Can you try running my script from my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570289/making-mercurial-subrepositories-behave-like-subversion-externals

I initially set them up as sibling repositories and then link the one as the parent to the other.  When doing that commit the hgsubstate gets updated.

Subsequently, I can clone the parent and get the kid as a subrepo w/o additional clones.

Comment: Call me stupid, but I don't see a script in your answer.  But I did find that if I alter the `.hgsubstate` file manually it works perfectly fine - other users will automatically pull the subrepos when they pull and update.  It's great, I'm just editing it manually.  *Almost there*

Comment: Ah, it was all thelines starting with a plus, which is the output of sh -x.  The .hgsubstate is supposed to get updated whenever you commmit in the parent repo or update in the child repo.  It gets its initial value (tip of the subrepo) when the initial clone of lib happens in my example.

Comment: Wow, I just had to clone the subrepo manually to get it off of the `00000000000000000000000000000000000000` substate.  I didn't realize that was a step.

Comment: Travis, do you recall what you had to clone? In my case, the .hgsub is pointing to an already cloned repo.

Comment: If you have the subrepo (`src/mylib` folder) cloned (as in: there is a `.hg` folder in your local directory), you `hg update` inside of that subrepo to the revision you want. Then running `hg commit` in the parent repo will change the contents of the `.hgsubstate` file to the correct revision.