# The Mercurial hgsubversion extension gets SVN Externals to behave like Hg sub repository

Tags: mercurial, hgsubversion, svn-externals

This question is related to *[Using the Mercurial hgsubversion extension with SVN Externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522317/using-mercurial-hgsubversion-extension-with-svn-externals)*. However, the second part of the question relating to doing a `hg svn update` has not been answered.

Is it possible to get the SVN externals in the subversion repository that you pull from to be converted into a Mercurial sub repository?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the original question also contains a partial answer to the externals problem you were having. However, could you just treat your configured externals as a regular Subversion repository folder and instead use `hgsubversion` to update Mercurial [Subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository)?

This obviously doesn't allow automatic handling of externals, but seems like a halfway decent solution to the problem (at least until the externals issue when not using the standard Subversion repository configuration is fixed in `hgsubversion`). It also looks like since Mercurial 1.5, the Subrepository feature can support other repository types for the subrepository like Subversion. See section 2.1.1 of the Subrepositories documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to manage your dependencies via Mercurial (or with any SCM for that matter), try using a dependency management tool instead, such as Apache Ivy.

More details in answer to [Hg sub-repository dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621670/hg-sub-repository-dependencies/7556836#7556836)

EDIT: Similar answer with a slightly different spin at [Best Practices for Project Feature Sub-Modules with Mercurial and Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851945/best-practices-for-project-feature-sub-modules-with-mercurial-and-eclipse/5906756#5906756)

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently have any support in hgsubversion for automatically turning externals references into hg repositories. I'd be somewhat open to that as a feature contribution, but it'd need to be well tested.